# Error in using ode45

Tags: matlab, ode

I am using pseudo-spectral method to solve a PDE, the transformed ODE is as below:

```
function rhs =  vhat(~, vhat0, ~, delta_t,kx) 
uhat = exp(1i * kx.^3 * delta_t) * vhat0;
u    = real(ifft(uhat));
u2   = u.^2;
g    = -0.5 * 1i * kx * exp(-1i * kx.^3 * delta_t);
rhs  = g * fft(real(ifft(u2)));
```

My main code is:

```
%----- Parameters for PDE -----
L       = 20;
n       = 2048;
delta_t = 0.001;
tmax    = 0.5;
c1      = 1.5;  % amplitude of 1st wave

x     = linspace(-L/2, L/2, n+1);
x     = x(1:n);
kx    = (2*pi/L)*[0:n/2-1 -n/2:-1]; 
tspan = 0:delta_t:tmax;


%-----initial condition
z1    = sqrt(c1)/2. * (x-0.1*L);
soliton = 6*0.5 * c1 * sech(z1).^2;
uhat0   = fft(soliton);
vhat0   = uhat0;

[t,vhat] = ode45('vhat',tspan, vhat0, [], delta_t,kx);

for j=1:length(t)
    w = real(ifft(vhat(j,:)*exp(1i * kx.^3 * j * delta_t)));
    plot(x,w)
    drawnow
    pause(0.2)
end
```

while running this code, I got error as below:

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in vhat (line 6)
g    = -0.5 * 1i * kx * exp(-1i * kx.^3 * delta_t);

Error in odearguments (line 87)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 113)
[neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir, y0, f0, odeArgs, odeFcn, ...

Error in kdvm (line 18)
[t,vhat] = ode45('vhat',tspan, vhat0, [], delta_t,kx);
```

Anyone here can help me out with this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could print out the matrix dimensions directly before the line causing the error.

The error itself is probably caused by the unintended matrix multiplication of `kx` with `exp(...)`. Insert the all important dot for element-wise multiplication.

---

Note that if `uhat = fft(u)`, then `ifft(uhat)` is, up to floating point errors, `N*u`. So you should always combine the `ifft` with a division by the dimension.

The line

```
rhs  = g * fft(real(ifft(u2)));
```

is almost surely wrong, since `u2` is a function of space, not of frequency, and input and output of this procedure are functions of frequency. I think you might have wanted to use

```
rhs = g .* fft(u2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @LutzL!. I did make mistake in dimensions. Now I checked all element wise multiplication by printing out every parameter, I think the dimension problems are fixed, however, there are still problems. The updated code of the function is '**_function rhs =  vhat(~, vhat0, ~, delta_t,kx)
ik3  = 1i * kx.^3;
uhat = exp(ik3 * delta_t) .* vhat0;
u    = real(ifft(uhat));
u2   = u.^2;
g    = -0.5 * 1i * kx .* exp(-ik3 * delta_t);
rhs  = g .* fft(real(ifft(u2)));_**' u2 is the function of u, u is the function of uhat, and uhat is the function of kx, so u2 is the function of frequency.

Comment: I found the error here. The **kx** here should be **kx.'** in Matlab. It should be transposed before conducting the following calculation.